# Limit of $S_n = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+i)^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

[WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim%20(sum%201%2F(a%2Bn)%5E2,%20n%20%3D%201%20to%20infinity),%20a%20to%20infinity) says that the sequence
$$
S_n = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+i)^2}
$$
tends to $0$. The proof given by the site uses notations unfamiliar to me, and was wondering if the following proves this.

Given $n$, we have that for all $N$,
$$
\sum\limits_{i=1}^N\frac{1}{(n+i)^2} = \sum\limits_{i = n+1}^{n+N}\frac{1}{i^2}\underset{N\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}\sum\limits_{i=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{i^2}
$$
which means that
$$
S_n = \sum\limits_{i=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{i^2}\underset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}0
$$

Is this proof valid? Is the order of taking limits not problematic?

Comment: $(n+i)^2 > n^2$.

Answer (score 3):

The proof can be rewritten
to make it simpler and clearer.

$\begin{array}\\
\sum\limits_{i=1}^N\frac{1}{(n+i)^2} 
&= \sum\limits_{i = n+1}^{n+N}\frac{1}{i^2}\\
&< \sum\limits_{i = n+1}^{n+N}\frac{1}{i(i-1)}
\qquad\text{since } i(i-1) < i^2\\
&= \sum\limits_{i = n+1}^{n+N}\left( \frac1{i-1}-\frac1{i}\right)\\
&=\frac1{n}-\frac1{n+N}\\
&< \frac1{n}\\
& \to 0 \text{ as } n \to \infty\\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 0):

Your thinking is along the right lines, but you are not reversing the order of two limiting processes here. There is just one limiting process and you are just reindexing. Here is how I would express it: If $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}x_m$ is any convergent series with sum $x$ say, then the "tail end" sequence $t_n= \sum_{m=n}^\infty x_m  = x - \sum_{m=1}^{n-1}x_m $ must converge to $0$. Putting $x_m = \frac{1}{m^2}$, your sequence $S_n$ is the tail end sequence of the convergent series $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{m^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

For positive monotonically decreasing functions, [the integral test not only applies, but it sets bounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence#Remark):

$$\int_{N+1}^\infty\frac1{x^2}dx\le\sum_{i=N+1}^\infty\frac1{i^2}\le\frac1{(N+1)^2}+\int_{N+1}^\infty\frac1{x^2}dx$$

Which converges to $0$ as $N\to\infty$ by squeeze theorem.